# Create Database Table and Add Records from JSON File

Tags: php, mysql, json

Actually, I have three main issues coming up. Firstly I have 1 JSON file containing about 1 million records. I want to create a database from that file but the issue is the JSON is multilevel (as I am a newbie to this type of work) I don't know which approach would work in this scenario.

I choose to work on PHP and MySQL. When I tried to create a database there is an issue with the JSON file that it does not contain a comma at the end of the row like this.

```
{
    "id": "IwrE5aE1DJ1v-juBWsVODg_0000",
    "full_name": "dianne webster",
    "first_name": "dianne",
    "middle_initial": "w",
    "middle_name": "wahl",
    "last_name": "webster",
    "gender": "female",
    "birth_year": null,
    "birth_date": null,
    "linkedin_url": "linkedin.com/in/dianne-wahl-webster-258578190",
    "linkedin_username": "dianne-wahl-webster-258578190",
    "linkedin_id": null,
    "facebook_url": null,
    "facebook_username": null,
    "facebook_id": null,
    "twitter_url": null,
    "twitter_username": null,
    "github_url": null,
    "github_username": null,
    "work_email": null,
    "mobile_phone": null,
    "industry": null,
    "job_title": "music teacher and director",
    "job_title_role": "education",
    "job_title_sub_role": "teacher",
    "job_title_levels": [
        "director"
    ],
    "job_company_id": null,
    "job_company_name": null,
    "job_company_website": null,
    "job_company_size": null,
    "job_company_founded": null,
    "job_company_industry": null,
    "job_company_linkedin_url": null,
    "job_company_linkedin_id": null,
    "job_company_facebook_url": null,
    "job_company_twitter_url": null,
    "job_company_location_name": null,
    "job_company_location_locality": null,
    "job_company_location_metro": null,
    "job_company_location_region": null,
    "job_company_location_geo": null,
    "job_company_location_street_address": null,
    "job_company_location_address_line_2": null,
    "job_company_location_postal_code": null,
    "job_company_location_country": null,
    "job_company_location_continent": null,
    "job_last_updated": "2020-09-01",
    "job_start_date": null,
    "job_summary": null,
    "location_name": "baltimore, maryland, united states",
    "location_locality": "baltimore",
    "location_metro": "baltimore, maryland",
    "location_region": "maryland",
    "location_country": "united states",
    "location_continent": "north america",
    "location_street_address": null,
    "location_address_line_2": null,
    "location_postal_code": null,
    "location_geo": "39.29,-76.61",
    "location_last_updated": "2020-09-01",
    "linkedin_connections": null,
    "inferred_salary": "45,000-55,000",
    "inferred_years_experience": null,
    "summary": null,
    "phone_numbers": [
    ],
    "emails": [
    ],
    "interests": [
    ],
    "skills": [
    ],
    "location_names": [
        "baltimore, maryland, united states"
    ],
    "regions": [
        "maryland, united states"
    ],
    "countries": [
        "united states"
    ],
    "street_addresses": [
    ],
    "experience": [
        {
            "company": null,
            "start_date": null,
            "end_date": null,
            "title": {
                "name": "music teacher and director",
                "role": "education",
                "sub_role": "teacher",
                "levels": [
                    "director"
                ]
            },
            "location_names": [
            ],
            "is_primary": true,
            "summary": null
        }
    ],
    "education": [
    ],
    "profiles": [
        {
            "network": "linkedin",
            "id": null,
            "url": "linkedin.com/in/dianne-wahl-webster-258578190",
            "username": "dianne-wahl-webster-258578190"
        }
    ],
    "certifications": [
    ],
    "languages": [
    ],
    "version_status": {
        "status": "unchanged",
        "contains": [
        ],
        "previous_version": "12.0",
        "current_version": "13.0"
    }
} ***//the comma should be here on each row.***
```

***at the closing curly brace, the comma should be used but I don't know how to do it.***

1. How to create the database in the best possible way?
2. I want to load the data from the JSON file into the database as there will be 84 columns in the database how I will create the mother-loving query for insert update and delete?
3. how I will create the array thingy in the database to store profiles and other stuff containing arrays in the database

***Looking forward to your answers as I don't know where to share my concerns.***
****THANKS****

Comment: basically you have to convert unto raays and then rebuild the hole by hand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949658/how-can-i-parse-nested-json-and-store-into-mysql-database

Comment: Thanks I got the point but how should I reformat the JSON and add a comma after every nested line

Answer (score 0):

here is how I solved these issues

1. I found that we can use any type of database as far as it is normalized and stores all the data as per the requirements.
2. you can use the [software](https://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/ultraedit-download/) on a trial version that can help you validate a large JSON file within seconds.
3. you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php) for the extracting arrays it helped a lot